# drupal database managemant

Tags: drupal, search, database-connection, user-profile, user-management

I'm new to drupal. i'm using drupal 6.x. i'm trying to make project to collect tuition teachers database. this is what i need,
if some teacher need to add his data to my site first he have to create an account, then he need to fill form like address, teaching subject, city, upload his photo, class details . ...ext. first part done

and if some one need to find a teacher, i need put a search box with following option.

1. search by subject
2. search by city
3. search by grade

search result by list of summery about teachers and if click once give full details.

I hope you can get what i need, my english is poor, sorry for that.

can anyone give me a idea how do i do this by drupal. what needy modules, what is the easiest way to create teachers database, how do i search that

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you read up on CCK (for the custom fields you'll need for your application) and Views with Exposed Filters (for your search + results).  There are a variety of tutorials on each of these findable via Google (as well as the module pages for [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)), also for their integration you might check out:

http://summapro.com/drupal-tutorials/learning-exposed-filter-views-search-and-filter
http://www.cliffordx.com/pgs/2/2010/how-use-views-exposed-filter-block